# How to make an onclick div in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Invest()
{
    alert("Mechanical /n Electrical /n Computer /n Civil");
}
function create()
{
    alert("Graphic /n Interior /n Architecture");
}
function motivate()
{
    alert("Business Administration /n Accounting and Finance");
}
</script>
```

The above code is my javascript code

```
<form action="main.html" method="post">
   <?php
    $v2 = $_GET['dropdown'];
 if ($v2=="investigative" )
    {
        echo "<h3>It's recommended that you follow</h3><h2>Engineering School</h2>";
    }
else if ($v2=="creative" )
    echo "<h3>It's recommended that you follow</h3><h2>Arts School</h2>";
else if ($v2=="motivated" )
    echo "<h3>It's recommended that you follow</h3><h2>Business School</h2>";              
?>
```

What i want to do is to change my echo to a div onclick so it will call my function from javascript and show the information i have inside it.

Something like this

```
 echo ""<div onclick=Invest();"<h3>It's recommended that you follow</h3><h2>Engineering School</h2>";
```

When I do that thought i get an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'onclick' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\eval.php on line 35

What am I doing wrong and how to make that work? I am new at php :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected++%28T_STRING nearly 800 and counting. Developers love error messages because googling them almost always provides the answer.

Comment: Use a text editor with syntax highlighting. Also, get in the habit of googling error messages. Believe me, thousands and thousands of people have asked this question before, and it is not difficult to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Not something like this `echo ""<div onclick=Invest();...`

You need to do it like this put div tag inside double quotes for onclick attribute open single quotes because double quotes are already opened

```
echo "<div onclick='Invest()'><h3>It's recommended that you follow</h3><h2>Engineering School</h2></div>";
```

Comment: Now it's finally working! Thank you ! I only have to change my alert now and i believe it will be fine :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I would rather do `echo '<div onclick="Invest()">...';` just to be consistent when I use double quotes in HTML.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid He's been here 9 months, 7 questions, negative net vote of -4, voted only twice for other content, and accepted one answer. Don't expect too much from a [vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). Better yet, don't encourage it.

Comment: @MikeB Now i realize after reading the vampire problem, voted to close